# Standard UIButton with custom image

Tags: iphone, image, sdk, uibutton

I'm trying to add a custom image on a standard `UIButton`. I know of the `setBackgroundImage` and `setImage` methods to do that. However, this will remove the 'standard' borders! Using `UIButtonTypeCustom` or `UIButtonTypeRoundRect` gives the same results...

Can this be so hard? 
A normal button like those in the `navigationbar` - just a custom image instead of the `titleLabel`. Do I really have to draw the button itself in an image editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do have to draw a custom image.

Comment: Thats what I hoped not to hear ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can add a subview of image to the UIButtonRoundRect. So just create a RoundRect button the usual way:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonRoundRect];
```

then create an image view with your image and add it as subview to the button:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *)image];

[button addSubivew:iv];
```

That should do the trick. Plus you can also set the position of that imageview by `[iv setCenter:CGPointMake(x,y)];`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, the idea of adding the image as a subview is nice. However, using the UIButtonRoundRect does not provide me with the 'standard' button look. Thanks anyway!

Comment: How did you get this to work? I get the warning `'UIButton' may not respond to '-addSubview:'` and then the app crashes when it hits that line.